# Changing the status of my paper in a job application

Tags: application, job

Two days ago, I have applied for a lecturer job and my CV & cover letter included a paper which was under review at that time. Yesterday, I got this paper accepted and will be soon published.

As an accepted paper makes a difference in employability in my field, should I notify the university of the new status of my paper? If so, should I send the email to the HR department or the Head of the academic unit? And what is the best thing to write in my email?

Comment: How did you apply for this job? By e-mail, through a website, .... ? And in what country is the position?

Comment: @Anonymous through their career portal, it is in the UK.

Comment: Can you apply again and overwrite your previous job application? The first thing I would do would be to contact some HR-type person to see if this is possible/recommended. If nobody has read your job application yet, you don't want to bug the people who will actually evaluating your application. Alternatively, if someone has, you probably want to try and guess who, and let them know.

Comment: @Anonymous Unfortunately the deadline has passed. But I did contact the  HR Manager.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sending an updated resume to the same address where you sent your first CV informing them of a recent change is perfectly acceptable. Be polite, mention the reason for the new CV, and you should be fine.